# How to prevent Xcode from trying to prepare my Apple Watch for development?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-watch

I am doing iOS development, on a phone, and attempting to build a phone-only app for just my phone. Unfortunately, my phone is paired with a couple of Apple Watches, and every time I try to run this phone-only app on my phone, Xcode decides it's time to prepare the watches for development. This process takes an indeterminate amount of time and never completes, all for a thing I have no immediate plans to do and is not helpful for my current situation.

I don't want to unpair the watches from my phone, so is there any way to tell Xcode to not try to prepare the watches for development when I'm only trying to run a single, simple app on just my phone?

Comment: This problem is not new and very annoying. Only workarounds exists (unpair, etc) but it's not satisfying. It looks like Apple developper do not use their own products. We need an option in settings to avoid that.

Comment: In my experience, just turning the Watch off works as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70936821/1265393

Answer (score 3):

It's just a workaround, but turn the Watch in the AirPlane mode for building…